# Group by and filter on 2 Distinct values in SQL

Tags: sql, sqltransaction

I have table T1

```
ID Size
A  1
A  2
A  3
B  3
B  4
C  2
C  4
```

I want to group by ID and filter the smallest size for each ID

Desired outcome:

```
A 1
B 3
C 2
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
SELECT ID, Size
FROM T1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM T1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a basic `GROUP BY` query:

```sql
SELECT ID, MIN(Size) AS Size
FROM T1
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I knew I was overcomplicating things. This problem was a paraphrase from a much larger issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.id, MIN(T1.SIZE) AS MinimumSize FROM T1 GROUP BY T1.ID
```

may be you can find your solution.

Comment: Oh cool. Thanks for the answer. I simplified a much larger issue to this simpler issue.